# Second Order PDE Cauchy Problem Heaviside

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

Consider the Cauchy problem $u_t = u_{xx} - a$ for $-\infty < x < \infty$, $t > 0$ with $a$ being a constant. $u(x,0) = H(x)$ where $H(x)$ is the Heaviside function.  Solve this using linearity and Duhamel's principle.

I tried using Duhamel's principle, but I get the error function and my professor said the answer will not include the error function

Comment: You're right, the solutions does involve the error function.

Comment: A trivial solution to the equation is $u(t,x)=-at$. So your solution should be $-at+v(t,x)$ where $v_t=v_{xx}$ and $v(0,x)=H(x)$. To solve the latter I think you will indeed get some kind of error function (because you need to convolve $H(x)$ with the heat kernel).